# Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000

Tags: redis, doctype, erp, erpnext, frappe

Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000

bench new-site test1.loc
MySQL root password:

Installing frappe…
Updating DocTypes for frappe : [========================================] 100%
Updating country info : [========================================] 100%
Set Administrator password:
Re-enter Administrator password:
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000
Please make sure that Redis Queue runs @ redis://localhost:11000

Tring to create new site in frappe but it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

Solution :
Just setup production auto and manual by running below commands:

For automatic :
sudo bench setup production username

then :

Supervisor:
sudo apt -y install supervisor
bench setup supervisor
sudo ln -s pwd/config/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/frappe-bench.conf

Nginx :
sudo apt -y install nginx
bench setup nginx
sudo ln -s pwd/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/frappe-bench.conf

Note: Here 'frappe-bench' is name of your bench.

sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
sudo systemctl restart supervisor
sudo bench restart

Please confirm and replace bench name as per yours.

And then run :
sudo bench new-site site_name --force

It will definitely work.

Happy Learning
Thanks :)

https://github.com/frappe/erpnext/issues/35632#issuecomment-1607450697

Answer (score 0):

Even this would help: [Install steps](https://github.com/TurkerTunali/Frappe-ERPNext-Version-14--in-Ubuntu-22.04-LTS)

PS: In step 16, sudo `bench setup production <<linux user's name>>`